# to find the children at all levels in python

Tags: python, json

I have a json tree of the form

```
{  
    "id":442500000904671234,
    "reply":0,
    "children":[  
        {  
            "id":442500532536893440,
            "reply":1,
            "children":[  
                {  
                    "id":442500826561785856,
                    "reply":1,
                    "children":[  
                        {  
                            "id":442501277688545280,
                            "reply":1,
                            "children":[  
                                {  
                                    "id":442501561940709376,
                                    "reply":1,
                                    "children":[  
                                        {  
                                            "id":442501884709199872,
                                            "reply":1,
                                            "children":[  

                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {  
            "id":442500099315597312,
            "reply":0,
            "children":[  

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to find the number of children at all levels of the tree. That means at any level I should know the number of children and the level number. I am not able to figure out how to keep both the level and the number of children jointly. 
I mean do i need to have a vector for which I have to keep the child and its level number always.

The code I could write is

```
def children(node):
print node
for child in node:
    level=1
    children(child)

level=0
count=0
with open("t1.json") as fr:
    for line in fr:
        j2 = json.loads(line);
        for child in j2['children']:
            children(child)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not entirely clear to me where you want that information to be. You could, for example, put it in the tree itself:

```
import json
t = json.load("t1.json")

def annotateTree(t,l=0):
    t["level"] = l
    t["number_of_children"] = len(t["children"])
    for child in t["children"]:
        annotateTree(child, l+1)

annotateTree(t)
```

Afterwards, at every level of the tree, you'll have two new attributes `level` and `number_of_children`.